# APIM Automation

Tags: automation, azure-api-management

I have multiple API's which I have exposed it via Azure API Management.

I am using one instance for across various environments. So currently I am adding / updating the API's / operations manually. Also I am setting cache, rewrite url for few of these operations. But now managing these are becoming a bit of too much work.
Is there a way, when any operation contracts changes in an API, I can then build / refresh the APIM and also setup the cache, re-write url, policies etc without manual intervention in APIM?

Comment: Using ARM deployment templates is probably your best approach.  We are currently working on guidance and tooling around this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider use [Swagger](https://buildazure.com/2017/10/20/swagger-is-now-the-openapi-specification/), the OPEN API in Azure to control the data flow with [Azure API policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies) for security and using [Azure provided REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/) to provision the APIm service and use the [App Service](https://stackify.com/azure-deployment-slots/) to build the backend.

General Concept Flow
AGW <> APIM <> API <> App Service